# How to wait for cookie is set in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have two scripts on my page:
script 1 sets a cookie, called 'myCookie' (sync)
script 2 gets myCookie value (async)

On the page script 2 is placed before script 1 (script 1 is tracking script it is placed strict before ).

At the moment script 2 doesn't see cookies set by script1. How can I get that cookies on pure JS?

Comment: How about having a `callback` function ?

Comment: You mean callback in script1? It's a tracking code so it's hard for me to change it's source

Comment: you can write setInterval function where you could poll the myCookie value and come out of it when ever myCookie is not null in script2

Comment: @ВладимирЗотов — How will you achieve desired output then ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with setInterval. Got something like this:

```
var i=0;
var u_id=0;
var int=setInterval( function() { 
    var re = /_pk_ses([^=]*)/;
    if(re.exec(document.cookie)!=null || i==5){
        if(re.exec(document.cookie)!=null){
            var m=re.exec(document.cookie);
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + '_pk_id'+m[1] + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            u_id=keyValue[2].split('.')[0];
        }
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.async = true;
        script.src = "http://myurl.com/script.js?u_id="+u_id;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        clearInterval(int);
    }
    i++;
} , 1000)
```